# Why do adjectives sometimes follow nouns in legal phrases?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-terms, legal-history

For example, consider the phrase "bodies corporate." Would the more natural English construction not simply be "corporate bodies"?

Why is the former form so often used?

Comment: Is it a remaining artefact of legal French?

Comment: Or of French legal?

Comment: The phrases are not synonyms “corporate bodies” is a strange reference to the physical bodies of the shareholders, “bodies corporate” is a reference to corporations in general.

Comment: Are you certain that a corporate entity can't alternatively be reffered to as a corporate body?

Comment: In a certain sense, the two words even mean largely the same thing: corpus actually just means "body", iinm.

Comment: @Seekinganswers not really "body corporate" is linguistically a compound noun - not a noun and an adjective - it has its own meaning independent of the meanings of body and corporate..

Comment: @DaleM but even if one accepts that "body corporate" is a compound noun, it nonetheless comprises a noun and an adjective that can be productively combined as "corporate body" with precisely the same meaning as "body corporate."  Its meaning is not at all independent of the meanings of "body" and "corporate."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The postpositive adjectives in many legal noun phrases in English—attorney general, fee simple—are a heritage from Law French.
>
> [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_French)

See also the [Norman Conquest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norman_Conquest) of England

And also see [section 69](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2005/15/section/69?timeline=false) SOCPA2005, specifically at s.69(3)(a) and s.69(4)(a), for the use of "*body corporate*" in [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) legislation.

Comment: Conveniently, this is also how you get people to stop calling you a bastard and start calling you a conqueror ....